# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Equivalence.equals() exception

Tags: hadoop, jar

I am trying to execute a map reduce job on hadoop 2.4.1 with guava 15.0 jar but i am getting the below mentioned exception. Did any one face the same issue?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:      com.google.common.base.Equivalence.equals()Lcom/google/common/base/Equivalence;
at com.google.common.collect.Interners$WeakInterner.<init>(Interners.java:68)
at com.google.common.collect.Interners$WeakInterner.<init>(Interners.java:66)
at com.google.common.collect.Interners.newWeakInterner(Interners.java:63)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Throughout Hadoop 2.4.x Guava 11.0.2 is used](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/branches/branch-2.4/hadoop-project/pom.xml?view=markup&pathrev=1583249).

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

Those are (as you already found out) incompatible with each other. So you will need to downgrade your 15.0 to 11.0.2, or something that is similarly compatible.

Comment: what is dependent guava version for 2.9.1 hadoop verison @Thomas Junglut